# Android 11(R) - Ask Every Time permission - Denied

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-11

Permission "Denied" status is returned when setting Microphone permission to "Ask Every Time" from the App info -> Permissions -> Microphone -> "Ask Every time".

Following code returns "Denied"

```
ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio);
```

Permission "Granted" status is returned when setting Microphone permission to "Ask Every Time" from runtime system permission dialog.

Setting permission from device settings also should give permission status as "Granted".

Could you please help?

This issue occurs in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems no problem as you said. If setting "Ask Every Time" , the app need to request each time, it will return "Granted" status. Otherwise, each time will return   "Denied" status. Therefore, you need to ask for permission on runtime.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#requesting-permissions

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, then it should behave same when I give "Ask Every Time" permission from Run time system permission request dialog correct?  
While I give "Ask Every Time" permission from Run time system permission request dialog. I get permission as "Granted" even after killing and relaunching the application.
And android 11 have limitation of showing system permission request dialog. Only two times (aprox) runtime system permission request dialog will be shown.

Comment: Hi, from the App info -> Permissions -> Microphone -> "Ask Every time", it means the app hasn't got the permission and just select a configure for permission.However, from runtime system permission dialog that mens you are requesting the premission.Once you choose "Ask Every time" on runtime, meanwhile it will get the permission. It is different with the Settings of mobile.

Comment: Okey, if be helpful. Would you mind I update this as the answer?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Okey

Comment: Hi, I have updated it as an asnwer.  Remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ***App info -> Permissions -> Microphone -> Ask Every time***, it means the app hasn't got the permission and just select a configure for permission. However, from runtime system permission dialog that mens you are requesting the premission. Once you choose **Ask Every time** on runtime, meanwhile it will get the permission. It is different with the **Settings** of mobile.

If setting **Ask Every Time** , the app need to request each time, it will return **Granted** status. Otherwise, each time will return **Denied** status. **Therefore**, you need to [ask for permission on runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#requesting-permissions).